# Unbounded range()

Tags: python, range, generator

Is there an unbounded version of `range` (or `xrange` for Python 2), or is it necessary to define it manually?  For example

```
squares = (x*x for x in range(n))
```

can only give me a generator for the squares up to `(n-1)**2`, and I can't see any obvious way to call `range(infinity)` so that it just keeps on truckin'.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're describing the basic use of [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools
squares = (x*x for x in itertools.count())
```