# Looping from 1 to infinity in Python

Tags: python, loops

In C, I would do this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0;; i++)
  if (thereIsAReasonToBreak(i))
    break;
```

How can I achieve something similar in Python?

Comment: I'm no python expert but `while (true): if reasonneeded(i) break i = i+1` Should work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python unbounded xrange()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186336/python-unbounded-xrange)

Comment: In C this would cause an overflow and not go to "infinity"

Comment: Shouldn't the title of this question be changed to "Looping from 0 to infinity in Python"? You're simply trying to have an "infinite `range`", so you can avoid `while True: i += 1`

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(start=1):
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

In Python 2, `range()` and `xrange()` were limited to [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize). In Python 3 [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-range) can go much higher, though not to infinity:

```
import sys
for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):  # you could go even higher if you really want
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

So it's probably best to use `count()`.

Comment: This also plays nicely with `takewhile` : `for x in takewhile(thereIsAReasonToContinue, count()):`

Comment: For me, `for i in range(sys.maxint)` breaks with a `MemoryError`. You also mentioned `xrange()` which works.

Comment: @scai, in Python3 `range` replaces Python2's `xrange`. In Python2 `range` creates and returns an actual list of ints. You won't have enough RAM for such a big list

Answer (score 27):

```
def to_infinity():
    index = 0
    while True:
        yield index
        index += 1

for i in to_infinity():
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 17):

Simplest and best:

```
i = 0
while not there_is_reason_to_break(i):
    # some code here
    i += 1
```

It may be tempting to choose the closest analogy to the C code possible in Python:

```
from itertools import count

for i in count():
    if thereIsAReasonToBreak(i):
        break
```

But beware, **modifying `i` will not affect the flow of the loop** as it would in C.  Therefore, using a `while` loop is actually a more appropriate choice for porting that C code to Python.

Comment: The most C-like doesn't mean the most pythonic. The most pythonic is using `itertools` and it should be recommended unless it's needed to modify i.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a `for` loop, it's possible to combine built-in functions [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254214)) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for an infinite `for` loop which has a counter. We're using `iter` to create an infinite iterator and `enumerate` provides the counting loop variable. The start value is zero by default, but you can set a different start value with the `start` argument.

```py
for i, _ in enumerate(iter(bool, True), start=1):
    input(i)
```

Which prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Reiterating thg435's comment:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

def thereIsAReasonToContinue(i):
    return not thereIsAReasonToBreak(i)

for i in takewhile(thereIsAReasonToContinue, count()):
    pass # or something else
```

Or perhaps more concisely:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

for i in takewhile(lambda x : not thereIsAReasonToBreak(x), count()):
    pass # or something else
```

`takewhile` imitates a "well-behaved" C for loop: you have a continuation condition, but you have a generator instead of an arbitrary expression. There are things you can do in a C for loop that are "badly behaved", such as modifying `i` in the loop body. It's possible to imitate those too using `takewhile`, if the generator is a closure over some local variable `i` that you then mess with. In a way, defining that closure makes it especially obvious that you're doing something potentially confusing with your control structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing that in C, then your judgement there is as cloudy as it would be in Python :-)

For a loop that exits on a simple condition check at the start of each iteration, it's more usual (and clearer, in my opinion) to just do that in the looping construct itself. In other words, something like (if you need `i` after loop end):

```
int i = 0;
while (! thereIsAReasonToBreak(i)) {
    // do something
    i++;
}
```

or (if `i` can be scoped to *just* the loop):

```
for (int i = 0; ! thereIsAReasonToBreak(i); ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

---

That would translate to the Python equivalent:

```
i = 0
while not there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
    # do something
    i += 1
```

Only if you need to exit in the *middle* of the loop somewhere (or if your condition is complex enough that it would render your looping statement far less readable) would you need to worry about breaking.

When your potential exit is a simple one at the *start* of the loop (as it appears to be here), it's usually better to encode the exit into the loop itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
def infinity():
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        yield i


for i in infinity():
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Cleanest and nicest approach imo.

Comment: Yes, very clean, I hadn't quite grokked the power of `yield` other than for lazy sequence generators, but a friend recently used it to provide a `pushd/popd` function without having to maintain an explicit stack. Very clever, it was.

Comment: Although I like the approach, infinity is now a range. Zero is not part of infinity if you ask me. Oh, and it is a badly reworded version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884284/589259).

Answer (score 2):

```
def natural_numbers():
  yield from map(sum, enumerate(iter(int,1)))

for i in natural_numbers():
  if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
      break;
```

Comment: There are **7 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **150 votes**. Why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important here where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help future readers out by explaining what your answer does different and under what circumstances it might be preferred.