# Changing While loop to a For loop

Tags: python

I am learning about the differences between for loops and while loops in python.
If I have a while loop like this:

```
num = str(input("Please enter the number one: "))
        while num != "1":
            print("This is not the number one")
            num = str(input("Please enter the number one: "))
```

Is it possible to write this as a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Very clumsy. Clearly a `for` loop is not appropriate here

```
    from itertools import repeat
    for i in repeat(None):
        num = str(input("Please enter the number one: "))
        if num == "1":
            break
        print("This is not the number one")
```

If you just wanted to restrict the number of attempts, it's another story

```
    for attempt in range(3):
        num = str(input("Please enter the number one: "))
        if num == "1":
            break
        print("This is not the number one")
    else:
        print("Sorry, too many attempts")
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking not really, because while your `while` loop can easily run forever, a `for` loop has to count to *something*.

Although if you use an iterator, such as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python), then that can be achieved.