# Are infinite for loops possible in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, infinite

Is it possible to get an infinite loop in `for` loop?

My guess is that there can be an infinite for loop in Python. I'd like to know this for future references.

Comment: I was looking something similar and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Imo, *"infinite loop"* and *"looping from 1 to infinity"* are not the same. `while True` is a good answer to the first, but not to the latter.

Answer (score 48):

You can use the second argument of [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), to call a function repeatedly until its return value matches that argument. This would loop forever as 1 will never be equal to 0 (which is the return value of `int()`):

```
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    pass
```

If you wanted an infinite loop using numbers that are incrementing you could use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

for i in count(0):
    ....
```

Answer (score 26):

The quintessential example of an infinite loop in Python is:

```
while True:
    pass
```

To apply this to a for loop, use a generator (simplest form):

```
def infinity():
    while True:
        yield
```

This can be used as follows:

```
for _ in infinity():
    pass
```

Comment: Hmm, but this is a while loop, not a for loop.

Comment: That is totally okay! I appreciate it though. Now I know while loops can be infinite as well! (:

Comment: @Britni.M I've updated the answer to include an appropriate generator in its simplest form.

Comment: 1. I don't think you are correct that it will fail, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer 2. Even if it does "fail" by overflowing to a smaller value (as would happen in a language in C) it would still be infinite, just the numbers would not be unique

Comment: @Jon ah, interesting. Still, unnecessary code, but I've updated my answer to remove the incorrect assertion. Btw, I didn't down vote you (I noticed somebody came by and down voted both of us while I was typing this).

Comment: @orokusaki ...sounds suspicious, not everyone works for votes

Comment: @Omkaar.K glad to see new people signing up to this abandoned platform to read 3-year-old comments

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use a generator that always yields another number:
Here is an example

```
def zero_to_infinity():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

for x in zero_to_infinity():
    print(x)
```

It is also possible to achieve this by mutating the list you're iterating on, for example:

```
l = [1]
for x in l:
    l.append(x + 1)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) can go much higher, though not to infinity:

```
import sys

for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):  # you could go even higher if you really want but not infinity
    pass
```

Comment: This will create a *big* loop, yes, but not an infinite loop, so I don't think it answers the question. I mean, yes, it'll probably run past the death of our sun, but why bother when there are so many good solutions creating actually infinite loops?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution using the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) module:

```py
import itertools

for _ in itertools.repeat([]):  # return an infinite iterator
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to combine built-in functions [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254214)) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for an infinite `for` loop which has a counter:

```py
for i, _ in enumerate(iter(bool, True)):
    input(i)
```

Which prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

This uses `iter` to create an infinite iterator and `enumerate` provides the counting loop variable. You can even set a start value other than `0` with `enumerate`'s `start` argument:

```py
for i, _ in enumerate(iter(bool, True), start=42):
    input(i)
```

Which prints:

```
42
43
44
45
46
...
```

Answer (score -1):

While there have been many answers with nice examples of how an infinite for loop can be done, none have answered why (it wasn't asked, though, but still...)

A for loop in Python is syntactic sugar for handling the iterator object of an iterable an its methods. For example, this is your typical for loop:

```
for element in iterable:
    foo(element)
```

And this is what's sorta happening behind the scenes:

```
iterator = iterable.__iter__()
try:
    while True:
        element = iterator.next()
        foo(element)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

An iterator object has to have, as it can be seen, a`next`method that returns an element and advances once (if it can, or else it raises a StopIteration exception).

So every iterable object of which iterator's`next`method does never raise said exception has an infinite for loop. For example:

```
class InfLoopIter(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self # an iterator object must always have this
    def next(self):
        return None

class InfLoop(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return InfLoopIter()

for i in InfLoop():
    print "Hello World!" # infinite loop yay!
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python infinite for loop

Well, there are a few ways, but the easiest one I found is to **Iterate over a list**

To understand this you must be knowing about:

- python basics
- python loops
- python lists ( and also its `append()` function

The syntax is something like this...

```py
l = ['#']   # Creating a list

for i in l:   # Iterating over the same list
    print(l)
    l.append(i)   # Appending the same element
```

With every iteration, the an element gets appended to the list. This way the loop never stops iterating.

Happy coding : )

Comment: Well, true, this creates an infinite for loop, but it is accompanied by infinite memory requirements, which is likely to be a problem for most code needing such an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

Best way in my opinion:

```
for i in range(int(1e18)):
    ...
```

The loop will run for thousands of years

Comment: How's that better than simple and obvious `while True`?

Answer (score -2):

The other solutions solutions have a few issues, such as:

- consuming a lot of memory which may
  cause memory overflow
- consuming a lot of processor power.
- creating deadlock.
- using 3rd party library

Here is an answer, which will overcome these problems.

```
from asyncio import run, sleep


async def generator():
    while True:
        await sleep(2)
        yield True


async def fun():
    async for _ in generator():
        print("Again")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(fun())
```

In case you want to do something that will take time, replace sleep with your desired function.

Answer (score -2):

we can actually have a for infinite loop

```
list = []
for i in list:
   list.append(i)
   print("Your thing")
```

Comment: I do not think it's infinite. It will run out of memory or bounds eventually.

Answer (score -2):

i found a way without using yield or a while loop.
my python version is python 3.10.1

```py
x = [1]
for _ in x:
    x.append(1)
    print('Hello World!')
```

if you need loop count, you can use i+1:

```py
x = [1]
for i in x:
    x.append(i+1)
    print(f'Hello {i}')
```

you should know that this is not really an "infinite" loop.
because as the loop runs, the list grows and eventually, you will run out of ram.

Comment: This (imo bad) *solution* is already shown in several answers here, for example in the [answer by @DeepaRajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34253996/850848#70631201).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if you test DeepaRajesh's answer, it actually doesn't work, len of the list must be at least 1.

Comment: True. So see the answer by @SahajOberoi. And it's still not a good solution. Simple `while True`  will do.

Answer (score -3):

You can configure it to use a list. And append an element to the list everytime you iterate, so that it never ends.

Example:

```
list=[0]
t=1
for i in list:
        list.append(i)
        #do your thing.
        #Example code.
        if t<=0:
                break
        print(t)
        t=t/10
```

This exact loop given above, won't get to infinity. But you can edit the `if` statement to get infinite `for` loop.

I know this may create some memory issues, but this is the best that I could come up with.

Comment: I do not think it's infinite. It will run out of memory or bounds eventually.

Answer (score -3):

```
n = 0
li = [0]
for i in li:
    n += 1
    li.append(n)
    print(li)
```

In the above code, we iterate over the list (li).

- So in the 1st iteration, i = 0 and the code in for block will run, that is li will have a new item (n+1) at index 1 in this iteration so our list becomes [ 0, 1 ]
- Now in 2nd iteration, i = 1 and new item is appended to the li (n+1), so the li becomes [0, 1, 2]
- In 3rd iteration, i = 2, n+1 will be appended again to the li, so the li becomes [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]

This will keep on going as in each iteration the size of list is increasing.

Comment: You can do without variable `n`: `li.append(len(li))`

Comment: I do not think it's infinite. It will run out of memory or bounds eventually.

Answer (score -4):

In Python 2.x, you can do:

```py
my_list = range(10)

for i in my_list:
    print "hello python!!"
    my_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your post? If yes, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but even more important is to add some explanation. Because code-only answers like this are rarely considered helpful.

Comment: This really does not answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

i'm newbie in python but try this

```
 for i in range(2):
         # your code here
         i = 0
```

can improve this code

Comment: This loop will run exactly two times so I'm not sure how it answers the question for getting an infinite loop... I'm guessing that you have the notion that doing `i=0` inside the loop will somehow *"reset"* the loop variable so it will run forever. This is not true. You should just run it and see for yourself...