# How to save values from a "for" loop? Python 3

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Yesterday I posted a question where I was searching for a way to do an infinite **`for`** loop, without using **`while`** at all (*because my teacher wants so*, and also, we can't use any commands *we haven't seen in class*). It was difficult as apparently there wasn't a very viable option that didn't use `while`, or other functions like `itertools` or .append, etc.

You can see that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46762884/8674022)
Also, thanks a lot for the feedback you guys brought me! :)

---

**But** I managed to talk with my teacher and we got permission **to use** `itertools` or just a range big enough (instead of actually infinite).

---

I solved a few exercises already, but now I have the following **instructions:**

> (Think about ***grades***)
>   • Ask the user a number (*through inputs*), and ***keep asking*** until the user tells to stop.
>   • Then, calculate the **average** from all the numbers entered.

(It's actually a little more complex, but I shortened it and I believe I can deal with the rest)

As I said, I **must** use a `for` loop, and I **can't** use `whiles` at all.

If I could use *while*, I'd do something like this:

```
def grades():
    totalg = 0
    countg = 0
    keepAdding = "y"
    while(keepAdding == "y"):
        qualif = int(input("Insert grades obtained, in scale from 0 to 100 "))
        totalg = totalg + qualif
        countg = countg + 1
        keepAdding = str(input("Do you wish to keep adding data? (y/n) "))
    print("The average of your grades is", totalg/countg)
```

How can I do something like that, but with **`for`** loops? I have no idea on how to store the data for later calculation.

---

Also, I'm interested into knowing a more "proper" way to be able to end the loop, but I can't use a **`break`** neither.

Thanks in advance! Any advice is appreciated and welcome! :)

Comment: In yesterday's answer I used `return` to get over the no-`break` restriction. Or aren't you allowed to use `return` either?

Comment: Maybe you should list the stuff you are allowed to use. It's hard to answer this type of question when we don't know what the rules are.

Comment: Yes. (sorry for the late btw) I can use return and it's more or less what I've done, but in this case, for this code for example, how would I put the return command in order to end it while keeping the variables value? Sorry for my ignorance, I guess it's something I could deduce from your code, but I'm afraid I haven't been able to understand it fully.
And yes, let me do a list of the stuff we've seen to make it easier. But I think we're getting closer though, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is, without outside modules, is to use [two-arg `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter); when passed two arguments, the first is a no-argument function to call over and over, and the second is a sentinel value than indicates you should stop.

So for example, you could make an infinite loop with something as simple as:

```
 for _ in iter(bool, True):
```

Since the `bool` constructor returns `False`, a sentinel value of `True` will never occur, so that's an infinite loop.

Similarly, to make a loop that prompts until the user responds with a given sentinel string, like `'q'` for quit (or just the empty string), you could do:

```
for inp in iter(lambda: input("Insert grades obtained, in scale from 0 to 100 (type 'q' to quit)"), 'q'):
    val = int(inp)
    ... rest of loop ...
```

Obviously, this is a little obscure (two-arg `iter` is rarely seen), so usually you'd use `while True:` with the loop containing a test-and-`break` or test-and-`return` (the latter doesn't violate the letter of the teacher's requirements). Similarly, exception handling can be used to exit the loop, though it's ugly:

```
 try:
     for ...:
         if test_for_end:
             raise StopIteration
 except StopIteration:
     pass
 # You're outside the loop
```

Note: Literally everything I've mentioned is terrible style, aside from an actual `while True:` loop with a test-and-`break`/`return` case. But you've got one hand tied behind your back, so I'm suggesting some terrible mutant hands to substitute.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Possible. One-arg `iter` isn't totally unheard of though, so they might have seen it, even if they weren't introduced to the two-arg form. If they went over the built-in functions, it's there; similarly, if they covered how a for loop works, `iter` is an implicit part of all `for` loops, so who knows?

Comment: I believe I'd be able to use iter know, well, actually, at first I believed it was included in iter.tools and my teacher allowed that. We haven't seen it in class, that's sure, but know I think I could use it. However, I seen some other things we wouldn't been able to use, like `lambda`.

I think I'm making you guys struggle a little too much, really, thanks a lot for this. But I think it'd be easier if as @PM2Ring says, I did a list with stuff we have seen. Give me a second, it'd be useful for me too

Answer (score 4):

Even though 'no-**break**' rule and a request for a "proper" way to end a loop are somewhat contradictory, I'd say that is possible, even without **return** :

```
grades = [0]
for j in grades:
    t = int(raw_input('grade:'))
    ans = raw_input('more? [y/n]:').lower()
    if(ans == 'y'):
        grades.append(t)
    else:
        grades[0] = t

print(sum(grades)*1.0/len(grades))
```

here we just iterate over ever-growing list of values, and when we need to stop - we simply stop adding values to it, and the loop ends.

**HOWEVER** 
This is NOT a proper way of handling that issue, read ShadowRanger for more details - this is bad coding style and should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe saving all the data obtained in an array?
I think arrays on python work as Linked Lists, so you won't have any overflow problems, at least that would be a starting point

Comment: One: No, Python isn't using linked lists for the `list` type (`array` is a module for C specific types, and probably not what you mean). Two: This isn't really an answer; it sort of responds to the title of the question, but the body of the question isn't about storing the original values at all; even if it was, this is too vague/broad to serve as an answer.