# Infinite for loop in Python like C++

Tags: python, for-loop

In `C++` we can write an infinite for loop like `for(;;)`. Is here any syntax like this  to write an infinite for loop in Python?

Note : I know that if I write `for i in range(a_very_big_value)` then it may run infinity. I am searching a simple syntax like `C++` or any other tricks to write `infinite for loop` in Python.

Comment: It's a `while loop`, I am searching for `for loop`.

Comment: Why do you _need_ a for loop?

Comment: I have `C++` background, that's why I am searching for something like `C++`. You can say it curiosity.

Comment: If you have a C++ background, think about it this way: how would you write an infinite range for loop in C++? That's much closer to what Python's `for` loop is than the C-style for loop.

Comment: yeah, nice point to notice. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `for` statement is a "for-each" loop (sort of like [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in C++11 and later), not a C-style "for-computation" loop.

But notice that in C, `for (;;)` does the same thing as `while (1)`. And Python's `while` loop is basically the same as C's with a few extra bells and whistles. And, in fact, the idiomatic way to loop forever is:<sup>1</sup>

```
while True:
```

---

If you really do want to write a `for` loop that goes forever, you need an iterable of infinite length. You can grab one out of the standard library:<sup>2</sup>

```
for _ in itertools.count():
```

… or write one yourself:

```
def forever():
    while True:
        yield None

for _ in forever():
```

But again, this isn't really that similar to `for (;;)`, because it's a for-each loop.

---

<sub>1. `while 1:` used to be a common alternative. It's faster in older versions of Python, although not in current ones, and occasionally that mattered.</sub>

<sub>2. Of course the point of `count` isn't just going on forever, it's counting up numbers forever. For example, if `enumerate` didn't exist, you could write it as `zip(itertools.count(), it)`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

With a `while` loop:

```
while True:
   ...
```

With a `for` loop (just for kicks):

```
from itertools import cycle    
for _ in cycle(range(1)):
    ...
```

The `cycle` returns `1` indefinitely.

In either case, it's up to you to implement your loop logic in such a way that you terminate eventually. And lastly, if you want to implement an execute-until-___ loop, you should stick to `while True`, because that's the idiomatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884244/5280371) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254008/5280371)

Using [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count():
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

In Python2 xrange() is limited to sys.maxint, which may be enough for most practical purposes:

```
import sys
for i in xrange(sys.maxint):
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

In Python3, range() can go much higher, though not to infinity:

```
import sys
for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):  # you could go even higher if you really want
    if there_is_a_reason_to_break(i):
        break
```

So it's probably best to use `count()`

---

It is also possible to achieve this by mutating the list you're iterating on, for example:

```
l = [1]
for x in l:
    l.append(x + 1)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here you are:

```
for i in __import__("itertools").count():
    pass
```

The infinite iterator part was taken from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737196/is-there-an-expression-for-an-infinite-generator#5737588) If you really think about it though, a while loop looks way better.

```
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while True:
    # Do stuff here
```

Comment: I have asked for `for loop` not `while` loop :(

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in iter(str, "forever"):
...     pass
```

This may help. Because the iter() function creates an iterator that will call str() with no arguments for each call to its **next**() method[ This returns an empty string ]; if the value returned by str() is equal to the string "forever"(WHICH WILL **NEVER** HAPPEN AS `"" != "forever"`), StopIteration will be raised thus breaking the loop, otherwise the loop will continue running and this is the case for our loop.

REF: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter