# How to write infinite for loop in Python and make addition to variable from array item?

Tags: python, c++

I have a code which is was written in C++.
I want to convert this to Python 3, but there is some problem that starts from `for(;;)` 
loop to `res+=arr[i]`.
There is my C++ pattern:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n;
  vector<int> arr;

  for(;;){
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0) break;
    else arr.push_back(n);
  }

  int res = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
    res+=arr[i];
  }

  cout<<res<<" "<<arr.size();


  return 0;
}
```

And I want to convert to Python 3.

```py
from itertools import count

arr = []

for i in count(0):
  n = int(input())
  if(n==0): break
  else: arr.append(n)

res = 0

for i in arr:
  res+=arr[i]

print(res+" "+len(arr))
```

So there are several mistakes that are hidden from me because I am coding in C++.

Comment: `for i in arr:` in Python this actually gives the *values* of the elements in `arr`, not indices from `0` to `len(arr) - 1`. So you'd just need `res += i`.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ code is basically appending integers from user input until a `0` is encountered. The equivalent python code would be

```
arr = []
n = None
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    arr.append(n)
```

Then once it breaks out of the loop, it computes the sum of the values, in this case that is trivial in python

```
res = sum(arr)
```

Comment: I want to use for loop instead of while, is it possible?

Comment: A `while True` loop is more canonical in python, but [it is possible to write an infinite for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253996/infinite-for-loops-possible-in-python) instead

Comment: Asker's input loop is actually behaving exactly the way it's supposed to, the problem is with the summation afterward.

Comment: @ibragim Python's `for x in y:` doesn't correspond to C++'s `for(init;test;inc)`, but `for(auto x : y)`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that's wrong is using `i` from `for i in arr:`. When you say `for i in arr`, `i` is the value in each element, and not the index like you're using it. So instead you would use it as `res += i`. Then instead of using a `for i in count(0)` loop to loop essentially forever, you could use a `while True:`

Comment: I didn't see Cory's answer before I posted. His solution is probably the most pythonic way to solve it.

Comment: Just task given to use for loop

Answer (score 0):

for(;;) is basically an infinit loop so you can replace that by while(True) in your python code. Also there is no += in python so it would be res = res + arr[i].
Also the for loop is a bit different:

```
for i in arr:
    res = res + i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that will help you

```py
import sys

def cin(arr):
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for var in line.split():
            var = int(var)
            if var == 0:
                return arr
            arr.append(var)
def main():
    arr = []
    arr = cin(arr)
    res = 0
    for i in arr:
        res+=i
    print(str(res)+ ' ' + str(len(arr)))
main()
```