# Can I make a for loop go forever? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

If I have code like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    print("Hello")
```

Is there a way to make it print forever with a `for` loop?

Comment: Does it have to specifically be a `for` loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite for loops possible in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253996/infinite-for-loops-possible-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

If your for loop takes its data from a generator that runs forever, sure:

```
def infinite():
    while True:
        yield


for __ in infinite():
    print("Hello")
```

You asked if it could be done as a one-liner. Not like this, but with some trickery (and without cheating by just importing it from elsewhere like `itertools`):

```
for __ in iter(int, 1):
    print("Hello")
```

This works because `int()` will just return `0` endlessly, never reaching the sentinel value of `1`. I still feel it's cheating a bit though, you'd only ever do this to make the point that it can be done with `for` - obviously `while True:` is the way to go if you seriously need this.

You asked how `for __ in iter(int, 1):` works exactly. The documentation for `iter()` is fairly clear https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter, but the short version is that if two arguments are given, the second acts as a sentinel and the first argument has to be a callable which will be called with no arguments and until the sentinel value is returned, all values up to the sentinel will be yielded from the iterator.

For example:

```
from random import random


def coin_flip():
    return 'heads' if random() > .5 else 'tails'


print(list(iter(coin_flip, 'heads')))
```

Here, `coin_flip()` is a function that returns `'heads'` or `'tails'` at random, with an about 50/50 chance. `iter(coin_flip, 'heads')` creates an iteratable that will call `coin_flip()` and yield the result until it returns the sentinel value (which won't be yielded).

So, there's a 50% chance you get `[]`, a 25% chance you get `['tails']`, a 12.5% chance you get `['tails', 'tails']`, etc.

Another way to look at it, is a mock implementation of `iter()`:

```
def iter(callable, sentinel):
    while (result := callable()) != sentinel:
        yield result
```

This doesn't implement all of `iter()`s functionality though, since it works differently if you only call it with a single argument.

In the original answer, it works because `int()` will always return `0`, which never becomes `1`, so the iterator yields `0` forever.

Comment: Is it possible to make infiniate an one-liner?

Comment: I've added a suggestion to that effect

Comment: Hi, @Grismar can you please elaborate more about this `iter(int, 1)` works? Or any pointer?   I know `iter` but never knew it can work like that... Thanks.

Comment: I added some explanation, hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason it needs to be a for loop?

You could just use a while loop,

```
while True:
    print('hello')
```

To stop it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> on your keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like `itertools.count`:

```
from itertools import count

for i in count():
    print(i)
```

Comment: or `itertools.repeat("hello")`

Comment: What will happen if `i` finally reaches the max_size of int64?

Comment: @Starry-OvO. Python doesn't use int64. It has its own version of infinite precision integers. So nothing interesting will happen, the loop will just keep going until you run out of memory