# Mimic while-loop using only for-loops in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Having started to learn code with C, I had always assumed that for-loops and while-loops where essentialy always equivalent (as in one could always reproduce the behaviour of one using only the other). But in python while going from a for-loop to a while-loop is always trivial, I could not find a way to achieve the reverse.

**Is there any way, in python, to reproduce the behaviour of a while-loop (infinite looping) using only for-loops ?**

Here is a solution that doesn't work (because of the recursion limit) using a recursive generator:

```
def infinite_loopy():
    yield "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy"
    for x in infinite_loopy():
        yield x

#here starts the supposedly infinite-loop
for x in infinite_loopy():
    print(x)
```

Comment: @Aurora0001 It's not a duplicate of that question as I would like **no usage of while-loops**

Comment: The accepted answer of that question uses no while loops, so it's exactly what you want, yes? If not, why not?

Comment: @Kevin My bad I only checked the question. But yeah that would count as a solution.

Comment: Yeah somehow I missed the proposed duplicate and drafted an answer that was exactly identical with the accepted answer in that other question...

Comment: @Antti Haapala Does this realy count as a duplicate ? I feel like they are two different questions that append to have common answers.

Comment: @jadsq the **only** way you can have `for` loop iterate forever in Python is to have an iterable/iterator/generator of infinite length.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok, I didn't know if it was the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by writing a [non-`yield` iterator class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

```
class Infinite(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self): # For Python3, replace this with __next__
        return 1

# Loops forever
for i in Infinite():
    pass
```

(You can see it stalling on [ideone](https://ideone.com/D9h8cd) if you have the patience - it's like watching paint dry).

Comment: this solution is simple and pleasant to the eyes, +1

Comment: @Lost Many thanks!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the correct comment. For Python3, `next` should be replaced with `__next__` (updated in the question).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the two-argument version of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) as follows:

```
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    print('All your loops are belong to us!')
```

The 2-argument form of `iter` calls the first argument as a function with no arguments. If the returned value equals (`==`) the second argument, `StopIteration` is raised, otherwise the return value is yielded. `int()` called without arguments returns `0` which is of course not equal to `1` thus yielding 0 forever, and we have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) or [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import itertools

for _ in itertools.repeat(None):
    # infinite loop

for _ in itertools.count():
    # infinite loop

for _ in itertools.cycle([None]):
    # infinite loop
```

All of these *can* be represented by functions using `while` loops, but the `itertools` module is implemented in `c` (in cPython), and makes no use of `while` loops in [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L4119).  Similarly for [jython (java)](https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/7635c5999b8ed4d4c72ed211b116a972bb764368/src/org/python/modules/itertools/repeat.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), and even [PyPy (python)](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/eaf0960e857d66716ef8f935221d76ece34c984d/pypy/module/itertools/interp_itertools.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#interp_itertools.py-81).  The same is true for `count` and `cycle`.

Comment: It's still possible that they're internally implemented using a `while`, no? I think that's how the OP responded to Aurora's comment just under the question.

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) for itertools.repeat indicate that it is roughly equivalent to a function containing a `while`

Comment: @jadsq The [source for `repeat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L4119) has no use of `while` whatsoever.

Comment: @AmiTavory See edit

Comment: @RoadieRich Oh, good answer, then (in a completely different direction).

Comment: @RoadieRich Alrigth then, its not extremely idomatic but its fair enough.

Comment: @jadsq you don't get much more idiomatic than using the standard library for what it's designed for.

Comment: @RoadieRich That's true. I just meant it as in "bare bones" python.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.count()` in for loop.

```
import itertools

def infinite_loopy():
    x = "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy"
    for x in itertools.count():
        yield x

for i in infinite_loopy():
    print("All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy")
```

[Reference]
[Looping from 1 to infinity in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python)