# I need to represent infinite as integer in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite

I'm working in Python 3, Windows 10, PyCharm.

I'm building a small program that lets you input your age and returns "Happy {age}{termination, eg: st, nd}!"

The thing is that I want to somehow avoid the situation where you will write your age as 1041 and it'll say "Happy 1041th!". So I used `list(range(21, 1001, 10))` for the termination "st", for instance. However, I'd like to be able to use `infinite` instead of 1001. If I use `math.inf`, that's a float and it's not accepted in my code. Also, I can't convert it to int.

I'm thinking of using a `n` number that should be higher than say, 100, and have `list(range(21, n, 10))`, but I'm too much of a beginner to know how to do that.
Thanks for the help. Here's my code:

```
age = int(input('Type age: '))
if int(age) == 1:
    term = 'st'
elif int(age) == 2:
    term = 'nd'
elif int(age) == 3:
    term = 'rd'
elif int(age) in list(range(21, 1001, 10)):
    term = 'st'
elif int(age) in list(range(22, 1002, 10)):
    term = 'nd'
elif int(age) in list(range(23, 1003, 10)):
    term = 'rd'
else:
    term = 'th'
if int(age) >= 130:
    print("C'mon! you can't be THAT old, you geezer!\nStill, here you go:")
message = f"Happy {age}{term} birthday!"

print(message)
```

Comment: Suppose you could do `range(23, infinite, 10)`. When would the function ever end?

Comment: can't you use `if (21 <= age) and (age % 10 == 1):` ?

Comment: Why don't you use the max value of the integer using **sys** pkg. Like this: `range(21, sys.maxsize, 10)`

Comment: That's another interesting one I never knew of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to check membership in a massive `list` which will eat up a ton of memory. You can just check what you age `endswith`.

```
age = input('Type age: ')
if age.endswith('11') or age.endswith('12') or age.endswith('13'):
    term = 'th'
elif age.endswith('1'):
    term = 'st'
elif age.endswith('2'):
    term = 'nd'
elif age.endswith('3'):
    term = 'rd'
else:
    term = 'th'

if int(age) >= 130:
    print("C'mon! you can't be THAT old, you geezer!\nStill, here you go:")
message = f"Happy {age}{term} birthday!"

print(message)
```

Comment: I had no idea about `endswith`. Thank you so much!

Comment: I actually think this is the best approach. It opens a lot of other opportunities. How did you find such a gem?

Comment: It's been a while, but probably just reading the docs here. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods There's also a `str.startswith()` that can be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Modulo arithmetic is a better (and completely general) solution to this problem:

```
age = int(input('Type age: '))
if 11 <= (age % 100) <= 13:
    term = 'th'
elif age % 10 == 1:
    term = 'st'
elif age % 10 == 2:
    term = 'nd'
elif age % 10 == 3:
    term = 'rd'
else:
    term = 'th'
if age >= 130:
    print("C'mon! you can't be THAT old, you geezer!\nStill, here you go:")
message = f"Happy {age}{term} birthday!"

print(message)
```

Comment: First statement is a very neat solution.

Comment: Just need an addition to exclude 11, 12, 13:
`elif age % 10 == 1 and age != 11:`
Same with the rest.
In case `if 11<= (age % 100) <= 13:` was meant to do that, I don't understand how it would work.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @OvidiuLeonte that's what the first line in the `if` statement does see this demo: https://rextester.com/RVKS70128

Comment: I thought so too it just doesn't work when I run it in my code, like [Vinay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6399721/vinay-gupta) says

Comment: You do have `elif age % 10 == 1` not just `if age % 10 == 1`?

Comment: @OvidiuLeonte no worries - I'm glad we got it sorted out.

Comment: @Nick, so if there's two lines of `if` in the same function, the last `if` surpasses the first? Meaning, the last `if` doesn't play the role of `elif`, but it cancels the assumption of the previous one?
Thank you.

Comment: @OvidiuLeonte if there are two `if` statements they execute independently. In this case, the second `if` had conditions (e.g. `age % 10 == 1`) that matched those in the first (`11 <= age`), so the actions from the first `if` were overwritten.

Comment: Thank you. I now get it.

Comment: @OvidiuLeonte was there a reason you decided against this code? I'm curious?

Comment: @Nick I used the `endswith` suggestion in the end. This is also great, but it's just that I found the other one more elegant (even though maybe it isn't, I don't know; this is how I feel about it). I didn't mean no disrespect neither towards the help you gave me, nor the effort you put into this. Honestly, I would chose both this and the `endswith` solution if it'd make sense to use two solutions. Of course, this doesn't mean I didn't learn from what you offered. Our entire thread of discussion clearly suggests it. And I thank yo for that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need change to be list, if you change it to be list it may will be error. You just input `age in range(s, e, i)`. If you want higher like as infinity use like this `age in range(21, sys.maxsize**100, 10)`

```
import sys
inf = sys.maxsize**10
age = int(input('Type age: '))
if int(age) == 1: term = 'st'
elif int(age) == 2: term = 'nd'
elif int(age) == 3: term = "rd"
elif int(age) in range(21, inf, 10): term = 'st'
elif int(age) in range(22, inf, 10): term = "nd"
elif int(age) in range(23, inf, 10): term = 'rd'
else: term = 'th'

if int(age) >= 130:
    print("C'mon! you can't be THAT old, you geezer!\nStill, here you go:")
message = f"Happy {age}{term} birthday!"
print(message)
```

But, why you want to use `range` if there is easier than it? Like make it to be `string` and then check the last number.

```
age = int(input("Type age: "))
term = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"][3 if age%10 > 3 or age%100 in range(10, 20) else age%10-1]
if age > 130: message = "blah-blah-blah"
print(message)
```

Yes, I know the result is defferent. But, the next code I show you it's also can handle higher than hundred. Such as 101, on your code will be 101th; I think isn't correct. Variable `term` I  have input `ternary operator` or `conditional expression`.
In Python `[if_true] if [condition] else [if_false]`
In JS `condition? if_true:if_false`

[Looping from 1 to infinity in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python)

Comment: I solved it with `age.endswith('1')` and so forth, but some things here are interesting, even though not for something that has such an easy solution as the aforementioned one. It'll just take me a while to process it, as I'm a bit at the beginning. Thank you.

Comment: There is 3 Condition with "th" last digit with, 0, 1x, and 4-9. For 1x `age%100 in range(10,20)` and for 0 and 4-9 `age%10 not in range(4)`. Combine them and then become `if age%100 in range(10, 20) or age%10 not in range(4): term = "th"` Now for st, nd, and rd: `else: term = ["", "st", "nd", "rd"][age%10]`.

Comment: On my answer I use `ternary operator`. Don't worry, I'll explain. If we make list `t = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"]`, so "th" in index 3 `t[3]`. Ternary operator is `3 if age%100 in range(10, 20) or age%10 not in range(3) else arg%10-1`. We combine the both condition (see code in comment above). The final result is `term = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"][3 if age%100 in range(10,20) or age%10 not in range(4) else age%10-1]`

Comment: I had some time to play with your solution.
`inf = sys.maxsize**10` issues this error: _OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t_
I presume `**10` is there to enlarge the `sys.maxsize` number. I tried without it, left `sys.maxsize` instead. Got me this error:
_OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t_
I am getting to the other solution you proposed, because I think there's something to learn from it. However, I hope you can tell me something about these errors.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the concept behind `term = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"][3 if age%10 > 3 or age%100 in range(10, 20) else age%10-1]`

I know it's probably trivial, but I didn't get to learn something like that. It seems to me that `term` equals two lists, one of them clearly having 4 elements, order DOES matter, and the second is an `if` statement that includes `or`, `not`, `and` operators. It's this `if` statement that I don't understand at all.
I know I'm asking much, but do you think you could point me in the right direction? I really love this solution and I'd like to understand it.

Comment: Yes, I told you. If you convert it to list you will gey error. Because it's too large. Don't do this: `age in list(range(101, sys.maxsize**10, 10))`. Do this: `age in range(101, sys.maxsize**10, 10)`. You may don't know about list. If we input `term = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"][3]` same as `term = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"]; term = term[3]`. For the next indise `[]` is known as `conditional expression`. `h = "Hi, Mister!" if age > 30 else "Hi, Bro!"`, this code same as `if age > 30: h = "Hi, Mister!"; else: h = "Hi, Bro!"`

Comment: OK, it worked. 

 I just got really scared. It's A LOT I don't know. No, I didn't know about conditional expression. That's similar to _list comprehension_, isn't it?
Anyway, thank you. And... I'll keep digging in what you gave me here.