# How can I make a range from 1 to infinity in python

Tags: python

So as I said in my last post that I'm a very beginner at python I just wanna ask that can you range number between 0 to inf in python because if I use `range(1, float('inf'))` it would be an error so I guess that because in range() you can only put int not float also I can't change inf(which is now in float) into int because it can only be in float so pls help me.

ps sorry for my bad grammar I'm not a native speaker

Comment: 1 to infinity also means more than 1. So why don't you use that instead? Adding your case of using infinity will hlep.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884213/looping-from-1-to-infinity-in-python

Comment: There is no way, you can do this. `Inf` is not necessarily meant to be used just for saturating the numbers.

OK, anyway: You want to have a sequence from `1` to the maximum number that can be represented in MATLAB, right? So go with `1:realmax`. See [realmax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmax.html)

Comment: I guess you can write a generator to keep generating an ever increasing value.

Comment: thankyou very much for all the answer