# Print numbers from 1 to x where x is infinity in python

Tags: python, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Infinity - Any caveats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628026/python-infinity-any-caveats)
>   [python unbounded xrange()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186336/python-unbounded-xrange)

I have a question regarding Python where you code a simple script that prints a sequence of numbers from 1 to *x* where *x* is infinity.
That means, "*x*" can be any value.

For example, if we were to print a sequence of numbers, it would print numbers from 1 to an "if " statement that says stop at number "10" and the printing process will stop.

In my current code, I'm using a "for" loop like this:

```
for x in range(0,100):
    print x
```

I'm trying to figure how can "100" in "range" be replaced with something else that will let the loop keep on printing sequences continuously without specifying a value.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Hedde I don't see how it's a duplicate or how the other question even helps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.count():
    print x
```

With a simple `while` loop:

```
x = 0
while True:
    print x
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`y` can be a number.

```
for x in range(0,y):
    print x
```

you can't have `y` infinitely large or negative.  Following example will be useful I think.

```
>>> for y in range(0,):
...     print y
... 
>>> 
>>> for y in range(0,1000000000000000):
...     print y
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: range() result has too many items
>>> for y in range(0,-1):
...     print y
... 
>>>
```

Comment: I tried it, but an error appeared that said: "y is not defined"
Thanks for the help

Comment: There are no limits on how big a python "integer" can become -- It'll silently convert to a `long` and keep going until you run out of memory.

Comment: @mgilson : I corrected the answer. I said python limit..that is out of memory...I don't think my answer misguide. Thanks

Comment: @MaxWayne you have to first assign a value to y. e.g. `>>> y = 1000` then for loop statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a generator:

```
def infinity(start=0):
    x = start
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

for x in infinity(1):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=0
while True:
  print x
  x = x +1
```

Comment: I believe you wanted the incrementing inside the `while` loop.  I've put it there.  I also changed `While` to `while` to make it valid syntax.

Comment: @mgilson yes thanks sorry typo

Comment: `x = x +1` should be `x+=1`

Comment: @InbarRose -- `s/should/could/g` :-p -- Both will work, but your suggestion is probably a bit more idiomatic.