# how would I add a counter to this

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I want to add a counter to this code so every time the word ligma is printed it counts the number of times ligma was printed on the screen

```
import winsound
import time
from threading import Thread

def play_sound():
    for _ in range(10):
        winsound.PlaySound("dank", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        time.sleep(2.5)

thread = Thread(target=play_sound)
thread.start()

while True:
    print ('ligma')
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/7186336/1076479

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
while True:
    print ('ligma')
    count += 1
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: Was it playing before? This shouldn't stop it from playing.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that I wanted it to count that on screen

Comment: Just print the count with the ligma print.

    `print('ligma - {}'.format(count))`

output: `ligma - 1, ligma - 2, etc.`